# How to write an array as csv file content using php?

Tags: php, csv, fopen, fputcsv

I am importing a CSV file into my site which contain Hebrew language.While opening the CSV file in the notepad, the Hebrew language content are not enclosed by the quotes. The content which is not in quotes are not read in my site.
During the time of uploading this csv file is moved into another file.To enclose the Hebrew content with double quotes I tried the following code,but the file is not upldated.

```
$fileHandler = fopen('IMPORT_193', 'rw');
        while (($buffer = fgets($fileHandler))) 
        {
        $v=explode(',',$buffer);

        for($i=0;$i<count($v);$i++)
        {

            $val=trim($v[$i],'"');
            $v1[]= '"'.$val.'"';

        }

        fputcsv($fileHandler, $v1);
        }
```

I want to update the current content in the file with the new values with quotes as CSV . Is there any way to enclose the CSV content in a file with quotes?Waiting for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not (at least in this example) read and write to the same file at the same time.
Try this:

```
$fileRead = fopen('IMPORT_193', 'r');
$tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'CSVIMPORT');
$fileWrite = fopen($tempFile, 'w');
while(!feof($fileRead)) {
  $data = fgetcsv($fileRead);
  foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
    if(!is_numeric($value)) {
      $data[$key] = '"'.$value.'"';
    }
  }
  fputcsv($fileWrite, $data);
}
fclose($fileRead);
fclose($fileWrite);
rename($tempFile, 'IMPORT_193');
```

This should do the trick. I have not tested this. And you need to have permissions to overwrite the IMPORT_193 file.

Comment: using 'fgetcsv' the  values with quotes are read ,so I use 'fgets'. In your code I replace the while loop with the while loop which mention in my question.The file get write but only the first row is read every time,remaining content are not read when using 'fgetcsv'.@Thomas L